# How to delete everything in an array except the first index?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `people`. It has an array field `numbers`, where each document has a varying number of elements in said array.

My goal is to keep the elements in the 0th index and recursively remove the rest. How could I go about doing this?

For example:

```
{_id: 1, numbers: [100, 200, 300]},       ->   {_id: 1, numbers: [100]},
{_id: 2, numbers: [101, 201]},            ->   {_id: 2, numbers: [101]}
{_id: 3, numbers: [102, 202, 400, 500]},  ->   {_id: 3, numbers: [102]},
```

Comment: See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/.
Maybe something like `{ $push: { numbers: { $each: [], $slice: 1 } } }` could work. $slice: -1 would keep only the last element.

Comment: @Clashsoft That is perfect, thank you. Feel free to create a proper *Answer*, otherwise I will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative solution to @R2D2 is to use [`$slice`](https://mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/slice). Unlike `$first`, `$slice` works for more than one element.

```
collection.updateMany(
  {},
  { $push: { numbers: { $each: [], $slice: 1 } } }
);
```

You could also use `$slice: -1` to start from the last element.

See this on [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rUmSq4BdLVe).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator [$first](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/) in update pipeline as follow:

```
 db.collection.update({},
 [
  {
   $addFields: {
     numbers: {
       $first: "$numbers"
       }
     }
  }
],
{
 multi: true
 })
```

Explained:

Replace the "numbers" array in all documents with array with only the first element taken from "numbers"

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5Lqso-AiLQo)

If you want the "numbers" to be still of type array you can enclose the output from $first in square brackets [] as follow:

```
     numbers: [{
       $first: "$numbers"
       }]
```

[Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XFy9dSBYMPn)

Btw , $first is alias of [$arrayElemAt](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#mongodb-expression-exp.-arrayElemAt) that you can use to extract  other elements from the array ...

But afcourse the operation can be done via $slice as mentioned earlier by @Clashsoft